# Getting property "PermissionTemplateGuid" trows exception "The operation failed" during sending email

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to get a property "PermissionTemplateGuid" of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Mail during sending of email in VSTO add-in for Outlook, but sometimes it throws exception "The operation failed".

```
 public string PermissionTemplateGuid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mail.PermissionTemplateGuid;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mail.PermissionTemplateGuid = value;
        }
    }
```

Maybe, somebody can help me to understand why it happened?

Comment: What code do you have in the `ItemSend` event handler?

Comment: `void Application_MailItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
           
            try
            {
                ItemHelper item = OutlookHelper.GetItemType(Item);

                bool isPermissionSet = (item as MailItemHelper)?.PermissionTemplateGuid != null;
}
...`